# How to get string before hyphen

Tags: python

I have below filename:

```
pagecounts-20150802-000000
```

I want to extract the date out of above `20150802`
I am using the below code but its not working:

```
print os.path.splitext("pagecounts-20150802-000000")[0]
```

Comment: where did you get the idea for splitext?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The methods in `os.path` are mainly used for path string manipulation. You want to use string splitting:

```
print 'pagecounts-20150802-000000'.split('-')[1]
```

Comment: print 'pagecounts-20150802-000000'.split('-')[1] done my job.. thanks

Comment: just to nitpick: this would get the first part, I think OP wanted to get the second.

Comment: Great! If this answer helped you, please accept it so future visitors can see it.